# django one to one relationship deletes user model

Tags: django, django-models

```
class EngrRegModel(models.Model):
   engineer = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   skills_description = models.TextField()
   reg_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

   def __str__(self):
    return f'Engineer {self.engineer.username}'
```

I created this EngrRegModel that have one of its field in one to one relatonship with the Django User Model, the problem is that whenever an instance of EngrRegModel is deleted, the User is deleted also, i want it to be a one way street kind of implementation, such that when a User is Deleted the instance of EngrRegModel is deleted but when an instance of EngrRegModel is deleted the user shouldn't be deleted. How do i fix this?

```
    @login_required
    def engineerDeleteView(request):
       engineer_instance = EngrRegModel.objects.all().filter(engineer = 
          request.user)[0].engineer
       username = request.user
       if engineer_instance == request.user and request.method == 'POST':
          engineer_instance.delete()
           messages.success(request, f'{username}, You Are No Longer A Sky 
            Squad Engineer')
            return redirect('profile')
       else:
           print("NO")
           messages.warning(
                request, f'{username}, You Do Not Have Access To This!!!')
       return redirect('profile')
```

this is the view that handles the delete functionality

Comment: That is normally how an `on_delete=models.CASCADE` works. Are you sure you did not define a trigger on the database, or a signal at the Django level?

Comment: yes i did define a signal at the Django level that creates a user profile whenever a user is created but it has nothing to do with this very model, am new to django though

Comment: Nothing in your code would delete the `User` model. So we cannot answer your question, because it's not possible this happens with the code you're showing us.

Comment: I have included the view that handles the delete, could the problem be from there?

Comment: yes, your view is deleting the user. `engineer_instance` is the `engineer` of your `EngrEngModel` which is the `User` object.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem came from the View fixed:

```
    @login_required
    def engineerDeleteView(request):
        engineer_instance = EngrRegModel.objects.all().filter(engineer = 
            request.user)[0]
        username = request.user

        if engineer_instance.engineer == request.user and request.method == 'POST':
            engineer_instance.delete()
            messages.success(request, f'{username}, You Are No Longer A Sky Squad 
             Engineer')
           return redirect('profile')
        else:
          print("NO")
          messages.warning(
            request, f'{username}, You Do Not Have Access To This!!!')
       return redirect('profile')
```

Comment: Note that `[0]` will raise an exception if there is no engineer instance for this user. You're better off using a `try...except` construct: `try: engineer_instance = EngrRegModel.objects.get(engineer=request.user); <do stuff>; except EngrRegModel.DoesNotExist: <warn user>`

Comment: Ok i will do that, but the application is actually design to not show a delete button if the instance does not exist which will make it very unlikely for the error to occur

Comment: `EngrRegModel.objects.get(engineer=request.user)` vs `EngrRegModel.objects.all().filter(engineer = request.user)` the two statement above do they have different in efficiency? if yes which is better

Comment: No difference. You can `print(queryset.query)` where `queryset` is each of your two statements to see the SQL generated. Try this in the shell.